# モデル内でuseDbConfigを変更すると、hasManyアソシエーションがうまく動作しない

Tags: php, cakephp

データベースを切り替えたあとに、取得したデータの$hasManyアソシエーションした部分の一部が紐づかないです。

<テーブル>

- postsテーブル
- tagsテーブル
- posts_tagsテーブル（中間テーブル）

＜モデル＞

- post.php
- tag.php
- posts_tag.php($name = 'PostsTag')

＜db環境＞

- 開発環境（'develompent'）
- テスト環境（'testDb'）

※database.phpは省略

dbを切り替えた後に、取得したデータが正しくとれません。
下記を見てください。
postモデルに中間テーブルのモデルであるPostsTagを$hasmanyしています。  
このとき取得したデータである$dataの[PostsTag]には、PostsTagモデルのデータは取れますが、、、、、
**サブで定義した?[PostsTag_Sub]には、PostsTagモデルのデータは取れません！！！！！！！！！！！！！**

ちなみにdbを切り替えなければ、データは全て正しく取れます。

困ってます。教えてください。

```
//post.php

class Post extends AppModel
{

    public $hasMany = [
        'PostsTag',
        'PostsTag_Sub' => [
            'className' => 'PostsTag',
        ],
    ];

    public function getData()
    {
        //開発環境(development)にいる
        $oldDb = $this->Tag->useDbConfig; //development
        // テスト環境(testDb)に切り替える。
        $database = 'testDb';
        $this->dbChange($database);
        //データ取得
        $data = $this->find('all');
        print_r($data);
    }    
    //データベース切り替え処理
    public function dbChange($database)
    {
         $this->useDbConfig = $database;
         $this->tag->useDbConfig = $database;
         $this->posts_tag->useDbConfig = $database;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

この場合 `PostsTag` と `PostsTag_Sub` は同じクラスでも別インスタンスになるようですから、`PostsTag_Sub` に対しても DbConfig を変更する必要があるのではないでしょうか。

```
public function dbChange($database)
{
    $this->useDbConfig = $database;
    $this->PostsTag->useDbConfig = $database;
    $this->PostsTag_Sub->useDbConfig = $database;
}
```

※質問に書かれたコードとマニュアル等から推測しただけなので、動作確認はしていません